# Facing problem in submit button. From verification OTP screen it is not navigating to dashboard screen

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have made three activities these are:

1. sendOTPone
2. verificationOTPtwo
3. dashboard

When I clicked on submit button from OTP verification screen then it will not let me go in dashboard screen my app closes automatically after this. Can anyone tell me where I did the mistake?

XML code for verificationOTPtwo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".verificationOTPtwo">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/recieved" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="OTP Verififcation"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Please enter the OTP sent to you"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecond"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textmobileshownumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        //###############################################

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputotp1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputotp2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputotp3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputotp4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputotp5"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputotp6"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />


        </LinearLayout>

        //################################################

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Not received OTP ?"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecond"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textresendotp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="RESEND OTP AGAIN"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextFirst"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonotpsubmit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroundbutton"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_verify_otp"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />


        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Java code for verificationOTPtwo

```
package com.example.animatedsplashdemo;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class verificationOTPtwo extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputnumber1, inputnumber2, inputnumber3, inputnumber4, inputnumber5, inputnumber6;
    String getotpbackend;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verification_otptwo);

        final Button verifyButtonClick = findViewById(R.id.buttonotpsubmit);


        inputnumber1 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp1);
        inputnumber2 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp2);
        inputnumber3 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp3);
        inputnumber4 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp4);
        inputnumber5 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp5);
        inputnumber6 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp6);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textmobileshownumber);
        textView.setText(String.format(
                "+91-%s", getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile")

        ));

        getotpbackend = getIntent().getStringExtra("backendotp");

        final ProgressBar progressBarverifyotp = findViewById(R.id.progressbar_verify_otp);

        verifyButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!inputnumber1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber4.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber5.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber6.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    String entercodeotp = inputnumber1.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber2.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber3.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber4.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber5.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber6.getText().toString();

                    if (getotpbackend != null) {
                        progressBarverifyotp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        verifyButtonClick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                                getotpbackend, entercodeotp
                        );

                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        progressBarverifyotp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        verifyButtonClick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dashboard.class);
                                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                            startActivity(intent);


                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, "Enter the correct OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }


                                    }
                                });

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, "Please check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    //        Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, "OTP Verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, "Please enter the OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        numberotpmove();


        TextView resendlabel = findViewById(R.id.textresendotp);

        resendlabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        "+91" + getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile"),
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        verificationOTPtwo.this,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

                                Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String newbackendotp, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {

                                getotpbackend = newbackendotp;
                                Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, "OTP sended successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }
                );

            }
        });


    }

    private void numberotpmove() {

        inputnumber1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber2.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber3.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber4.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber5.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber6.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

dashboard.java :

```
package com.example.animatedsplashdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_open, R.string.navigation_close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
    2022-04-03 01:27:14.483 21162-21162/com.example.animatedsplashdemo 
       E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.animatedsplashdemo, PID: 21162
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.animatedsplashdemo/com.example.animatedsplashdemo.dashboard}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:581)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:183)
    at com.example.animatedsplashdemo.dashboard.onCreate(dashboard.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

Comment: Share your logcat also.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I have shared logcat also please take a look and try to help me out in this @VishalChauhan.

Comment: Share it from crash(where exception start). Although from this logcat I can assume the error is in dashboard activity for setting action bar.

Comment: I have shared the logcat from crash as well as code for dashboard screen @VishalChauhan.

Answer (score 0):

Set **windowActionBar** false in your AppTheme.

```
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Hope this will help you.